# Write text in persian on CapCut

Tags: app

When I edit a video in the capcut application and I want to put a text as an explanation in Farsi, the text entered in Farsi gets messed up. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked with the developers that their application is R>L capable?

Comment: [How to write Arabic Text in capcut - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZH-JSQnFjoo)

Comment: How is it messed up?

Comment: The text is reversed and separated